# Que veut dire « ne pas tenir à quelque chose » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je suis en train de lire un livre de grammaire et dans l'introduction on donne des phrases d'exemple mais sans donner les traductions.
J'ai cherché sur internet mais je n'ai rien trouvé. Donc je demande de l'aide.

Les phrases en question:

- Je ne tiens pas à eux.
- Je ne tiens pas à les voir.
- Je ne tiens pas à ce qu'on m'invite.

Que veut dire « ne  pas tenir à quelque chose » ?

Comment: generally : *don't care about* sometimes climbing up to **don't actually want**

Comment: Quand *tenir à* est utilisé dans la forme négative, il s'agit souvent d'une litote. Non seulement on n'éprouve pas un fort désir pour quelque chose ou quelqu'un, mais c'est bien le contraire que l'on sous-entend.

Answer (score 3):

C'est lié à la notion d'attachement.
Je tiens à les voir -> je suis attaché à voir ces personnes.
Je tiens à toi -> je suis extrêmement attaché à toi.
Nous tenons à cette personne -> Nous sommes attaché à cette personne que ce soit de manière amicale, par intérêt, amoureusement, par relation familiale etc...

La négation exprime donc un manque d'attachement ou d'affection envers une personne ou un objet.

En résumé : Je ne tiens pas à .. -> Je ne suis pas attaché/affecter à..

Answer (score 2):

*ne pas tenir à quelque chose* signifie en général *ne pas vouloir*, hormis dans le cas où l'on parle directement d'une personne, comme dans ta phrase :

> Je ne tiens pas à eux

*Eux* représentant un groupe de personne, on va plutôt traduire cette expression par *je n'aime pas vraiment ces personnes*

> Je ne tiens pas à ce qu'on m'invite

Dans ce cas, on parle d'une action, donc on utilise le cas plus généralisé du *je ne souhaite pas être invité* ou *Je ne veux pas être invité*

> Je ne tiens pas à les voir

Ici, on ne parle pas directement du groupe de personnes, puisque l'on ne souhaite tout simplement pas vouloir voir un groupe de personnes -> description d'une période temporaire, donc on peut traduire cela comme *Je ne souhaite / veux pas les voir*

Answer (score 2):

Pour la première phrase, la phrase peut se comprendre comme "ne pas avoir d'attachement (sentimental) pour cette personne".  A noter que l'attachement n'est pas nécessairement amoureux et peut concerner un objet personnel. Pour moi, ça ne veut pas dire qu'on n'aime pas ces gens (au point de les éviter, par exemple) mais plutôt qu'ils nous indifférent). Par exemple,

> je ne tiens pas à eux au point de prendre des risques inconsidérés.

Dans le cas des deux autres exemples, le sens est quelque peu différent, c'est plutôt similaire à "je n'ai pas envie".

Answer (score 1):

- Je ne tiens pas à eux : Je ne les aime pas (ou pas beaucoup)
- Je ne tiens pas à les voir : Je ne veux pas les voir
- Je ne tiens pas à ce qu'on m'invite : Je ne veux pas qu'on m'invite